# How to combine sets of similar data under common columns (a specific case)

Tags: r, merge

Here's a portion of a dataset that I have of daily closes for certain stocks within a common period of time in .xlsx format:

[image]

What I need is an R script that would produce something like this:

[image]

So I need a row for each stock everyday for the time period and the corresponding prices for them in the third column like above. Of course, I have more than 100 stocks for a period of 4 years. So that makes more than 100 rows for each day for 4 years. For example, a hundred rows of the day 5.01.2015 and so forth.

I'm still very new to R so help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: What have you tried? There are multiple ways of achieving this. In __Base R__: `reshape`. In __dplyr__:  `pivot_longer`. In __data.table__: `melt` to name a few.